# UITableViewCell loading wrong CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a weird behavior while loading background gradient depending on a date. 
My code should change the background gradient of a uitableviewcell depending on an existing date. If a date is in past the background gradient turns red, yellow for present and green for future dates.
So far, the code to get the correct state/gradient(red/yellow/green) works and will be displayed in console. Unfortunately not in the simulator/iPad.
To insert the background gradient im using

```
cell.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
```

Here begins the weird behavior. While loading the next few cells the background gradient turns randomly red/yellow/green. 
In fact when I'm using,

```
cell.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

the gradients will be displayed correctly depending on the date, but the labels Outlets won't be displayed anymore

```
UITableViewCell:

import UIKit

class TaskUITVCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var appointment: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var creator: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var assignedTo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnBookingCustomer: UIButton!
    var type:String = "-"
    var value:Int = 0

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
    @IBAction func btnclicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        //TODO open User / Booking
        print("Type: \(self.type) Value: \(self.value)")
    }
}
```

class TaskUITVC: UITableViewController

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath     indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TaskUITVCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TaskUITVCell

let due = overdueToActualDate(self.taskArray[indexPath.row])
let gradient = Gradients().cellNormal(cell.bounds, tint: due)
cell.layer.addSublayer(gradient)

self.dateFormat.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
cell.title.text = self.taskArray[indexPath.row].title
//Apointment Date
cell.appointment.text =  self.dateFormat.stringFromDate(self.taskArray[indexPath.row].date)

//Button: to choose correct type to open specific view controller

if (String(taskArray[indexPath.row]) == "TaskModel"){
    cell.btnBookingCustomer.hidden = true
}
if (String(taskArray[indexPath.row]) == "CustomerTaskModel"){
    cell.btnBookingCustomer.setTitle("Customer: \((self.taskArray[indexPath.row] as! CustomerTaskModel).customer_number)", forState: .Normal)
    cell.type = String(taskArray[indexPath.row])
    cell.value = (self.taskArray[indexPath.row] as! CustomerTaskModel).customer_number
}
if (String(taskArray[indexPath.row]) == "BookingTaskModel"){
    cell.btnBookingCustomer.setTitle("Booking: \((self.taskArray[indexPath.row] as! BookingTaskModel).booking_id)", forState: .Normal)
    cell.type = String(taskArray[indexPath.row])
    cell.value = (self.taskArray[indexPath.row] as! BookingTaskModel).booking_id
}
return cell
}
```

hopefully someone has a suggestion for this issue

Edit: added screenshot of the behavior from the two methods
Method insertSublayer displays the text, but background gradient is wrong. Methode addSublayer displays the gradient as expected, but no text 
[Pic: left side addSublayer, right side insertSublayer at the same indexPath.row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEu5C.png)

Somehow the pattern of the gradient in methods insertSublayer repeats.
Maybe it's some coaching issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/28460729/5786300
Instead of adding a new layer to the cell, the background view of the cell need to be modified